# How to detect JavaScript errors during parsing phase on browser to show friendly error page?

Tags: javascript, parsing, browser, error-handling, parsing-error

I have a React single page app.

I use error boundaries to display a friendly error page when something goes wrong with my code.

But this happened the other day.

- One of the packages I was requiring was not transpiled to ES5 and it contained an arrow function `() => {};`
- When I tested on an old browser (Samsung Internet v4), which does not support arrow functions, it simply broke the code probably during the `parsing` phase, right?
- So my Error boundarie had no chance of capturing the error. And I basically rendered a blank page.

**QUESTION**

This error happened during the JS parsing, right?

How can I detect that something went wrong during the parsing phase so I can render something useful, like: `Please update your ancient browser...`

Note: I have a `<noscript>` tag, but I guess that this is a different case.

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks. I do transpile my code with Babel, but I don't usually transpile any `node_modules` package, which was the culprit, in this case.

Comment: Ah, sorry, missed that